# Crystal Report(bind to datatable) no table error

Tags: c#, datatable, crystal-reports, dataset

I have datatable `dt` and I'm binding it to a crystal report

```
CustomReport rpt = new CustomReport();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(this.dt);
rpt.SetDataSource(ds);
```

and I'm getting `The report has no tables` error even though it does

[image]

what I had first. I used the DataTable directly seeing a proper overload of the SetDataSource method. but I got the same error, and after searching I found it's 'recommended' to `create new dataset at runtime and add your DataTable to the dataset before calling SetDataSource method`

any pointers are most appreciated

Comment: try to set `dt` as `DataSource` instead of `ds`.

Comment: @Bharadwaj actually that was what I had first. I used the `DataTable` directly seeing a proper overload of the `SetDataSource` method. but I had the same error, and after searching I found it's 'recommended' to `create new dataset at runtime and add your DataTable to the dataset before calling SetDataSource method`